# How to catch a casting issue in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, casting, apache-spark-sql

When using SparkSQL version 2.1.1 a *faulty* cast results in the target value being set to  (null). For example the following statement:

```
spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT cast(column_1 AS DECIMAL(3, 2) from table")
```

would result in this:

```
in:               out:
-------          ----------
| '1' |          | 1.00   |
-------          ----------
| 'b' |          | (null) |
-------          ----------
| '3' |          | 3.00   |
-------          ----------
```

In this case I would like to inform/ warn the user about this by spooling the number of occurrences and maybe even the affected line number. Is there a way to achieve this?

What I already tried is add a column to the DataFrame with the MD5 sum over all columns of each row for comparing the source and target DataFrame. In the example above this would, however, not work due to the added decimals.

Comment: Would it maybe be a solution to filter for _null_ and count the number of rows for which this occurs? Or in case it is possible that there are values missing before the cast to compare between the old and the new column if values change to _null_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try registering a UDF to catch errors and call it while casting.

```
val customCast = spark.udf.register("numCasting", (x:String) => scala.util.control.Exception.catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).opt(x.toDouble))
```

and then use it in DF

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked long back and was about spark version 2.1.1 but still answering if someone gets benefitted from it.

In spark version 3.0 or greater you can just set the spark configuration variable spark.sql.ansi.enabled to True and it will throw run time exceptions when your data has values that can be casted to the data type requested. The default value of this property is false.

You can set it as below:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.ansi.enabled","True")

Ref Link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a column marking whether the casting was successful and then do something useful with it (it has to be a *separate* column to keep the column types).

```sql
WITH `table` (column_1) as (
    SELECT '1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL
)
SELECT
    column_1 as input,
    cast(column_1 AS DECIMAL(3, 2)) as cast_input,
--     CASE -- pre 3.4 syntax
--         WHEN 
--             cast(column_1 AS DECIMAL(3, 2)) IS NULL AND 
--             column_1 is NOT NULL 
--         THEN FALSE
--         ELSE TRUE
--     END as cast_ok
    CASE -- Syntax supported as of spark 3.4
        WHEN 
            cast_input IS NULL AND 
            input IS NOT NULL 
        THEN FALSE
        ELSE TRUE
    END as cast_ok
FROM `table`;
```